# Add or Remove class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This looks awkward but when I'm trying to add any class or remove any class using jQuery it's not working, Instead of adding or removing class I tried with the alert window, in that case, it's working fine. Can anyone tell me why I'm not able to add or remove any class?

```
$('#sign').click(function(){
    alert("I'm working");
    $('#signup').ready(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

This is the code I've tried and `#sign` is the id in Sidebar or navbar whatever. When I click on that link then it goes to the section with id `#signup`. In this section I want that class to add or remove.

Comment: remove `$('#signup').ready(function(){` and use `$('#signup').toggleClass('hidden');`. Complete Code is: `$('#sign').click(function(){
    $('#signup').toggleClass('hidden');
})`

Comment: `ready` make no sense in this context (no trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

`$('#signup').ready(...)` does not seem applicable. The page is already loaded, so you do not need to wait for DOM ready. Just remove that wrapper and manipulate the class directly:

```
$('#sign').click(function(){
    alert("I'm working");
    $('#signup').addClass('hidden');
});
```

I am assuming you are trying to handle clicking on and changing the classes on DIFFERENT elements (despite the similar names).